# Immersive Mode, How to disable swipe navigation bar

Tags: java, android, android-immersive

How to disable swipe navigation bar.
In Immersive Mode, when I pull down or up on screen is shown navigation bar How To disable or ignore that

Thanks!

Comment: @duggu it's doesn't work

Comment: @Arpanßløødyßadßøy it's doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable it using DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED
Basically you are locking your Drawer so it won't open with gestures

To lock:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

To unlock:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```